# Как реагировать на изменения в popup. Из другого файла отвечающего за страницу (расширение)

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Пишу расширение для chrome. Столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть popup в котором кнопки. Файл подключен тут `"browser_action": {"default_popup": "popup.html"}`
Все его обработчики и js связанный с ним подключен к этому же файлу тегом script.
Так же есть файл с которого я хочу реагировать на изменения и управлять страницей в зависимости от нажатых кнопок в popup окне. Подключен тут `"content_scripts": [{"js": ["js/content.js"]}]`
Как мне это сделать?